# Deserialize LocalDate Optional with Jdk8Module throws error

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, option-type

I am testing `Optional`s with `Java 8` and I would like to `serialize/deserialize` `LocalDate` via `Json`. So I have created custom `Object Mapper` in which I register `Jdk8Module`:

```
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapperBuilder(){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

And my `Entity` class looks like:

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDate insertDate;

    public Item(){}

    public Item(LocalDate insertDate) {
        this.insertDate = insertDate;
    }

    public Optional<LocalDate> getInsertDate() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(insertDate);
    }
}
```

But when I do `GET` method from my controller which takes all `Item` data it throws:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
Could not write JSON: java.util.Optional cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate;
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
java.util.Optional cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate(through reference chain:
org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]
->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]
->com.inventory.models.Item["insertDate"])
```

Do you have any clue how to improve or what should I add to my code to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Having quite a little knowledge about your configuration and environment suspect that because you have member of type `LocalDate` but getter for that returns `Optional<LocalDate>` there will be confusion like error states.

Either one is propably wrong?

i would try - based on the exception-  to change:

```
public Optional<LocalDate> getInsertDate() {
   return Optional.ofNullable(insertDate);
}
```

to

```
public LocalDate getInsertDate() {
   return Optional.ofNullable(insertDate).get();
}
```

OR

change

```
private LocalDate insertDate;
```

to

```
private Optional<LocalDate> insertDate;
```

which might require changer to annotation and/or deserializer

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
```

OR

create a setter accepting  Oprional

```
public  setInsertDate(Optional<LocalDate> optLocalDate) {
    this.localDate = optLocalDate.get():
}
```